# How to speed ffmpeg-x264 encoder operation

Tags: android, ffmpeg, java-native-interface, arm, x264

i have ported ffmpeg-x264 for android but the issue is encoder takes more time to encode a frame .It takes above 100ms to encode and cpu  rises to 85% in some devices like LG and samsung.i am using the following avcodeccontext settings

```
c->bit_rate = 256000;
c->width = width;
c->height = height;
c->gop_size = 2;//75;
c->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
c->codec_type=AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
c->codec_id=CODEC_ID_H264;
c->cqp=36;
```

is there any other settings that makes the ffmpeg-encoding faster and utilizing less cpu percentage

Answer (score 0):

> If your computer is not fast enough, you can speed up the compression at the expense of the compression ratio. You can use ’-me zero’ to speed up motion estimation, and ’-intra’ to disable motion estimation completely (you have only I-frames, which means it is about as good as JPEG compression).

http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Tips

Comment: Hi i am using android mobile.so far video quality is good for gop size 2 and cqp 36.But the main issue is time taken by encoder.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you ask on x264-devel (http://mailman.videolan.org/listinfo/x264-devel).
They are working on asm version for ARM, including NEON support. I think they need help with that (they had some Google code-in help they need integrate). I'm sure Jason Garrett-Glaser has done profiling on ARM devices and knows the best settings and where there is most potential for performance wins.